# How to write a counter function for Vec<String> in Rust?

Tags: arrays, string, rust, hashmap

**Function name:** my_counter
**Input:** ['foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar']]
**Output:** {'foo': 1, 'bar': 4}

**Note:** The Output type is HashMap<String, usize>, but not HashMap<&str, usize>.

Here is my implementation which I believe is a little overhead. The 'bar' has been converted to string for four times, but might not needed.

```
pub fn my_counter(vec: &Vec<String>) -> HashMap<String, usize> {
    let mut result: HashMap<String, usize> = HashMap::new();
    for key in vec.iter() {
        let val = result.entry(key.to_string()).or_insert(0);
        *val += 1;
    }
    result
}
```

Anybody would like to share a better solution? Thanks very much~

Answer (score 4):

One thing you could do is avoid creating new `String`s by *consuming* (or *moving*) the original vector's values. Like this:

```
pub fn my_counter(vec: Vec<String>) -> HashMap<String, usize> {
    let mut result: HashMap<String, usize> = HashMap::new();
    for key in vec {
        let val = result.entry(key).or_insert(0);
        *val += 1;
    }
    result
}
```

Note the changed function signature: `vec` is now `Vec<String>`, not `&Vec<String>`.  If that, for some reason, is not acceptable, then you really can't avoid creating new `String` values for the `HashMap`'s keys. Let's say *N* is the number of vector items and *M* is the number of unique vector items. If you *know* you are gonna have lots of duplicate values in the vector (that is, *M* is much smaller than *N*), in theory you might be able to get away with creating only *M* new `String`s. However, Rust doesn't seem to provide *stable* methods to directly achieve that. If using Nightly is OK for you, maybe try [`raw_entry_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.raw_entry_mut).

An alternative approach might be to first create a temporary `HashMap<&str, usize>` and then convert it to the desired "fully owned" `HashMap<String, usize>`. However, it's likely that would only make things worse. It really depends on the keys you have. It is one thing to have short keys and a ratio of *M*:*N* about 0.5-1.0 and completely different if you have long keys and a ratio of, say, 0.0001.

If you have a good idea on the number of unique keys, you can definitely speed things up to some degree by simply creating the `HashMap` with `HashMap::with_capacity(...);`. Using an alternative to the default hasher could also help in theory, although I have only tried `FnvHashMap` and even for short `String` keys I couldn't get any significant speed-up.

Comment: Because I am new to Rust, so I am a little concerned to use `Nightly` version rust.
As far as I know as least in data analysis or data science area, most of time M:N should be less than 0.5, otherwise it does not make too much sense to count the elements. So I like the 2nd idea that covert the type of HashMap. Thanks so much~

Answer (score 1):

I can immediately imagine 3 other variants of doing this

- *See* first whether the entry already exists with `contains_key`, then either `insert` or update with `get_mut`
- *Blind*ly just `insert`, then re-`insert` if the first insert returned a previous value
- Build a `HashMap<&str, usize>` first, then convert that (doing the work of inserting *twice*).

The problem is, what is faster depends on the input data. How many strings there are, how long they are, how long the input Vec is.

I've [benchmarked](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f0d6a4961733d9afab647122cd1b11c0) 5 cases:

- `d1`: Your short example input data
- `few10k`: 10 unique strings of length 4 in an array with 10000 entries
- `many10k`: 10000 entries of length ≤8, nearly all unique
- `long`: 300 unique strings of length 300
- `mix`: All of the above

Here are the results

```
test d1_blind         ... bench:         331 ns/iter (+/- 5)
test d1_seeing        ... bench:         234 ns/iter (+/- 2)
test d1_tushushu      ... bench:         230 ns/iter (+/- 4)
test d1_twice         ... bench:         232 ns/iter (+/- 4)
test few10k_blind     ... bench:     727,628 ns/iter (+/- 4,557)
test few10k_seeing    ... bench:     302,445 ns/iter (+/- 3,282)
test few10k_tushushu  ... bench:     399,378 ns/iter (+/- 3,870)
test few10k_twice     ... bench:     173,828 ns/iter (+/- 2,431)
test long_blind       ... bench:      70,604 ns/iter (+/- 233)
test long_seeing      ... bench:      93,349 ns/iter (+/- 381)
test long_tushushu    ... bench:      69,862 ns/iter (+/- 231)
test long_twice       ... bench:      92,118 ns/iter (+/- 292)
test many10k_blind    ... bench:   1,060,656 ns/iter (+/- 65,839)
test many10k_seeing   ... bench:   1,148,671 ns/iter (+/- 58,452)
test many10k_tushushu ... bench:     957,733 ns/iter (+/- 5,392)
test many10k_twice    ... bench:   1,297,526 ns/iter (+/- 57,415)
test mix_blind        ... bench:   1,962,634 ns/iter (+/- 7,973)
test mix_seeing       ... bench:   1,617,921 ns/iter (+/- 45,453)
test mix_tushushu     ... bench:   1,519,876 ns/iter (+/- 4,872)
test mix_twice        ... bench:   1,597,130 ns/iter (+/- 11,068)
```

It seems your implementation performs best in most cases. You could go further and start mixing implementations, i.e. run `twice` until its `HashMap<&str, usize>` gets to a certain size, switch to your implementation. Since this problem appears in many places (e.g. also in sql databases, and those people love optimizing things to death), somebody probably has written a paper about the best method for it somewhere.

Comment: I am new to Rust, and actually I am not quite familiar with benchmarking. So it's super helpful to list the score for me. I think the idea to mix implementations is good and I also saw people using this way to solve other problems. (e.g. sorting array). Thanks very much~

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that to run the benchmark: (0) have rust nightly (1) `cargo new foobar` (2) put code from playground into `src/main.rs` (3) run `cargo bench`.

Comment: Thanks and let me try the `cargo bench`.